# formatting JSON from URL into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How do i go about taking the JSON that is output from a URL and format it in html.  The JSON i have looks like this:

```
prtg-version    "xxxxxxx"
treesize    0
channels    
0   
name    "Downtime"
name_raw    "Downtime"
lastvalue   ""
lastvalue_raw   ""
1   
name    "Execution Time"
name_raw    "Execution Time"
lastvalue   "19 msec"
lastvalue_raw   19
2   
name    "File count"
name_raw    "File count"
lastvalue   "431 #"
lastvalue_raw   431
3   
name    "Folder Size"
name_raw    "Folder Size"
lastvalue   "224,855,871 Byte"
lastvalue_raw   224855871
4   
name    "Newest File"
name_raw    "Newest File"
lastvalue   "1 s"
lastvalue_raw   1
5   
name    "Oldest File"
name_raw    "Oldest File"
lastvalue   "1 h 31 m"
lastvalue_raw   5476
```

Its updates every 15 seconds.  I want to format into a html table and remove some bulk.  I have tried some code from w3schools but this just returns: `[object Object],[object Object]`

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://myurl/api/table.json?blahblahblah", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `toString()` on an object generally results in `[object Object]`. You should `JSON.stringify` the field first.

Answer (score 0):

`field` is a reference to the objects you're looping over.  Outputting that to the DOM will coerce it to a string, hence you see the `[object Object]` output.

To fix this you instead need to access the objects properties and build the HTML you want to output. Also note from the context of the object and your code it looks like you should be looping over `result.channels`, not `result`. Try this:

```js
var result = [{
  'prtg-version': "xxxxxxx",
  treesize: 0,
  channels: [{
    name: "Downtime",
    name_raw: "Downtime",
    lastvalue: "",
    lastvalue_raw: ""
  }, {
    name: "Execution Time",
    name_raw: "Execution Time",
    lastvalue: "19 msec",
    lastvalue_raw: 19
  }, {
    name: "File count",
    name_raw: "File count",
    lastvalue: "431 #",
    lastvalue_raw: 431
  }
  // more data...
  ]
}]

jQuery(function($) {
  $("button").click(function() {
    // AJAX code removed from this demo, as it obviously cannot work
    // $.getJSON("https://myurl/api/table.json?blahblahblah", function(result){        
      $.each(result[0].channels, function(i, field) {
        $("div").append(`<p>${field.name}</p>`);
      });     
    // })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I'm not sure i have understood properly.  I see you have removed the 'getJSON' and specified it in code - doesn't this mean now that the data is no longer dynamic.  I'm trying to ta.

Comment: That it just for this example as I obviously can't recreate the AJAX request. The point is that the `$.each()` needs to be amended as instructed but still inside your AJAX callback. I'll amend the answer to make this more obious

Comment: I just can't get this to work when the getJSON is commented back in.